# Hibernate Spatial 4 and PostGIS 2.0

Tags: postgis, java, hibernate-spatial

I'm having some issues integrating these technologies:

- Hibernate Spatial 4.0-M1
- PostGIS 2.0.2 (with compiled JDBC 2.0.2)
- Hibernate 4.1.1

The specific error is:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.postgis.PGgeometry. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

The entity annotation is:

```
@NotNull
@Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Point geom;
```

And the Point creation example is:

```
Location location = new Location();
WKTReader fromText = new WKTReader();
Point geom = null;
try {
    geom = (Point) fromText.read("POINT(-56.2564083434446 -34.8982159791812)");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Not a WKT string:" + "SRID=4326;POINT(-56.2564083434446 -34.8982159791812)");
}
if (!geom.getGeometryType().equals("Point")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Geometry must be a point. Got a " + geom.getGeometryType());
}
location.setGeom(geom);
locationDAO.insert(location);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using Tomcat, and it's connection pooling facilities. I just exposed a datasource to my application [through JNDI](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+a+PostgreSQL+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat).

Here's what did work for me:

- When I included the maven dependency for hibernate-spatial, it has a transitive dependency for hibernate itself, postgresql's jdbc and postgis's jdbc. So what I did was to remove these dependencies (outdated). My pom looks like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Postgis jdbc is the extension to postgresql jdbc that you need.

- Then I cloned [postgis repository](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/) and compiled their jdbc extension. Just run `mvn package` in the `java/jdbc` directory. Read its readme.
- Then I placed the most recent postgresql-jdbc and the recently compiled postgis jdbc in the tomcat's `lib` directory
- On the tomcat's server configuration, I changed the database url to `jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://localhost:5432/mydatabase`. Notice the `postgresql_postGIS` part. I also changed the driver class to `org.postgis.DriverWrapper`. This is a wrapper that registers postgis types with the native jdbc.

Here's my final resource configuration in tomcat:

```xml
<Resource auth="Container"
          maxActive="120" maxIdle="10" name="jdbc/myapp"
          username="myuser" password="mypassword"
          poolPreparedStatements="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          driverClassName="org.postgis.DriverWrapper"
          validatingQuery="select 1"
          url="jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://localhost:5432/myapp"/>
```

This procedure is generally described in the postgis jdbc's README. So make sure you [read it](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/tree/svn-trunk/java/jdbc).